# Racket, generate a set of integers 2.n, then filter in items that are factors of n

Tags: racket

For example, from the docs:

```
(for/list ([i (make-integer-set '((2 . 3)
                                    (5 . 6)
                                    (10 . 15)))])
    i)
'(2 3 5 6 10 11 12 13 14 15)
```

Except, I only need 2.n. Then filter and return the factors of n.

So, how to get a list of factors of n using map/filter and a lambda.

This is what I have so far with a loop and counter:

```
(define (sum-factors [index 1] [n 0] [sum 0])
  (cond [(and (< index n) (= 0 (modulo n index))) ('(true))]))
```

I just want to add n  to sum if it is a factor of n less than n, then increment index by 1. How can I do more than one thing in the taken branch?

Still have bugs in here.

```
#lang racket
(define (sum-factors [index 1] [n 1] [sum 1])
  (cond [(and (<= index n) (= 0 (modulo n index))) (sum-factors (+ index 1) n (+ sum index))]
     [else (+ sum index)])
 )

(define (get-sum-of-factors n)
  (sum-factors 1 n 1))

(get-sum-of-factors 15)
```

Comment: `(require math/number-theory)` followed by `(divisors n)`

Comment: I think the test suite will reject using the number-theory library. It has to be my "own" implementation. I can do it with a loop easily, but that seems like writing C in Perl. What is the Racket idiom for generating and filtering a list?

Comment: What is the expected result? List of factors, list of pairs `(factor . exponent)` or sum of factors? What it should return for `15` or `1800`?

Comment: The sum of the set of factors excluding n, so for 8, 1+2+4, 12 1+2+3+4+6 = 16.

Comment: "...using map/filter and a lambda" -- is this part of the assignment (specifically using `map` and `filter`) ?

Comment: No, just my goal to get some finger exercises in on using map/filter. Rather than doing it like The Little Schemer, I wanted to use a different style.

Comment: Well, the test suite allowed number-theory and the divisors function, so that simplified my approach to aliquot numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Create list of numbers from 1 to `n` (excluding n) using [`range`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._range%29%29).
2. Use [`filter`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) to keep only numbers that are divisors of `n`.
3. Sum this list with [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29).

```
#lang racket

(define (divisors-sum n)
  (apply + (filter (lambda (d) (zero? (remainder n d)))
                   (range 1 n))))

(divisors-sum 8) ;=> 7
(divisors-sum 12) ;=> 16
```

Comment: It works, but when applied to the tests for the actual problem, it causes a memory overflow. So, I will try to think of ways to optimize.(divisors-sum 33550336)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you work with lists which can then run into memory issues as soon as n (and thus the size of this list) gets huge.

You can use streams (or generators) instead to drastically reduce your memory footprint.

#### Streams solution

Streams are very well explained in SICP (structure and interpretation of computer programs).

With Racket v8.3 this would be (thanks to @Shawn's remarks!)

```
(require racket/stream) ;; actually already in #lang racket

(define (stream-range start end (step 1))
  (if (>= (- start end) 0)
      empty-stream
      (stream-cons start (stream-range (+ start step) end step))))

(define (factors-sum n)
  (stream-fold +
               0
               (stream-filter (lambda (x) (zero? (modulo n x)))
                              (stream-range 1 n))))
;; try it:
(factors-sum 10)
;;=> 8 ;; 1 + 2 + 5 = 8
```

Since this version of `sum-factors` works with streams - during the calculation - at any time point - it holds only the result and maximally in addition the next number in the stream in memory - and thus doesn't hold the entire list of numbers in memory. Thus, it can handle much bigger `n`s without running out of memory.

In Python you are advised to use generators instead of lists.

In Racket, there is also a generator package which can deal with `yield`.

#### Generators solution

```
(require racket/generator)

;; create a function returning a generator for integers
(define (make-integer-generator (step 1) (start 1))
  (generator ()
             (let loop ([x start])
               (yield x)
               (loop (+ x step)))))

;; every call of `(integers)` gives the next successor of integers

(define (factor-sum n)
  (let [(result 0)
        (integers (make-integer-generator 1 1))]
    (let loop ([num (integers)])
      (cond [(>= num n) result]
            [(zero? (modulo n num))
             (set! result (+ result num))
             (loop (integers))]
            [else (loop (integers))]))))

(factor-sum 10) ;;=> 8
```

#### Old answer's code

```
#lang racket

(define (stream-take stream n) ;; I tried racket v6.11 - it didn't have stream-take
  "Take first n elements of a stream lazily"
  (if (zero? n)
      empty-stream
      (stream-cons (stream-first stream)
                   (stream-take (stream-rest stream) (- n 1)))))

(define (stream-reduce combiner init-val stream) ;; this is actually stream-fold
  "Reduce a stream lazily."
  (if (stream-empty? stream)
      init-val
      (combiner (stream-first stream)
                (stream-reduce combiner init-val (stream-rest stream)))))


(define (integers-from n (step 1))
  "Return an infinite stream of integers starting from n by step 1 or more."
  (stream-cons n
               (integers-from (+ n step) step)))

(define (stream-range a b (step 1)) ;; actually integers-from is a stream-range
  "Return a stream of integers from a to b-1 
   (b is excluded - in the style of python)."
  (let ((steps (ceiling (/ (- b a) step))))
    (stream-take (integers-from a step) steps)))
  
;; using all this you can define your desired function
;; which returns the sum of all numbers smaller than n 
;; and are divisors of n:
(define (sum-factors n)
  (stream-reduce +
                 0
                 (stream-filter (lambda (x) (zero? (modulo n x)))
                                (stream-range 1 n))))
```

Text was the same.

Comment: Racket has `stream-take` already. And `stream-fold`.

Comment: `(sequence->stream (in-range a b step))` too...

Comment: @Shawn - I see that in the docu - but my Racket v6.11 doesn't have `stream-take` for whatever reason. `stream-fold` - ah I forgot to look for `fold`.

Comment: 6.11? Wow, that's an old version.

Comment: I realized - it is because I am using sometimes this 32bit machine - and it doesn't upgrade to the newer version obviously.

Comment: but even in v6.11 - there was `stream-fold`. But `stream-take` was indeed missing. However, there is no need to use `stream-take` when using the self-defined `stream-range`. But thanks for telling my about the existing functions!

Comment: Odd that a basic operation like take wasn't added till later. Does 6.11 have the `srfi/41` module available? That has it too (and a `stream-range` and a ton of other stuff)

Comment: It started out kind of a “stupid” question, but the answers are extremely fruitful. I was aware of streams and generators, but now I know how to use them in one case and I think I can imagine other scenarios.

Comment: @bentaisan I added also generators solution.

Comment: @Shawn - I tried `$ raco pkg install srfi` and it worked! Then did `(require srfi)` in v6.11 - inddeed `stream-take` and `stream-range` were available then. Thank you! (Know the packages ...)

Comment: @bentasian Whenever you deal with huge files to read-through or huge data, streams and generators can save you. In bioinformatics, one easily runs into memory problems. That's why I had to learn about generators, streams and parallelizatiion ...

Answer (score 2):

A more idiomatic Racket way would be to use the [`for/sum` comprehension](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Fsum%29%29) instead of creating, filtering and summing lists:

```lisp
(define (sum-of-factors num)
  (for/sum ([n (in-range 2 num)]
            #:when (zero? (remainder num n)))
    n))
```

If you note that all factors of N (Not counting 1 and N) are going to be less than or equal to N/2, you can reduce the amount of numbers you have to check by half:

```lisp
(define (sum-of-factors num)
  (for/sum ([n (in-inclusive-range 2 (/ num 2))]
            #:when (zero? (remainder num n)))
    n))
```

This can be further refined by realizing that for all pairs of factors a and b of N, one will be less than or equal to the square root of N and one will be greater or equal. That means you can compute a pair at a time while looking at even fewer numbers:

```lisp
(define (sum-of-factors num)
  (let ([root (exact-floor (sqrt num))]) ; integer closest to 0 from square root
    (- (for/sum ([n (in-inclusive-range 2 root)])
         (let-values ([(q r) (quotient/remainder num n)])
           (if (= r 0) (+ n q) 0)))
       (if (= (sqr root) num) root 0)))) ; Special case for when the root is a factor so it doesn't get counted twice
```

If you really want to use lists, there's `divisors` from the `math/number-theory` module, which I suspect is more efficient for large numbers:

```lisp
(- (foldl + 0 (divisors num)) num 1)
```